# NSManagedObject to TextField

Tags: swift, textfield

I want to display the Data in NSManagedObject into the TextField. All i get is the error:

```
[<ItemDetail: 0x6050003790b0> (entity: ItemDetail; id: 0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://4A94A10C-7A8B-42DC-8D48-30800667D9F9/ItemDetail/p1> ; data: <fault>)]
```

I am trying:

```
TextView.text = "\(Detail)"
```

Detail is defined as:

```
var Detail: [NSManagedObject] = []
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
TextView.text = "\(Detail)"
```

says:

1. Take the variable `Detail`
2. Turn it into a string
3. Assign the string to `TextView.text`

The question is: what is `Detail`?  You say that `Detail` is defined as follows:

`var Detail: [NSManagedObject] = []`

That means that `Detail` is an array of `NSManagedObject` instances.

So what you are telling the computer to do is, take an array of `NSManagedObjects`, turn the array into a `String`, and assign it to `TextView.text`.

What you *probably* want to do is take one of the objects out of the array, access a property of the object (for example: `name` or `title` and assign the value of that property to `TextView.text`.

For instance:

```
if let firstItemDetail = Detail.first { 
    TextView.text = "\(firstItemDetail.name)"
}
```

Comment: I actually want to save the "text" from the TextField into the NSManagedObjects. Not as an Array maybe, but as an "array" that saves all the input and displays it back into the same TextField when i come back to the ViewController. Step 1-3 is what i want, but how can i realize that code for the TextField or TextView? :/